# Long to wide dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the consumption of alcohol for different beverages (Beer, Wine, e.t.c.) for all the countries for the year 1961 - 2019. The dataset looks like below:

```
      Country Year                  Beverage consumption
1 Afghanistan 2019                      Beer           0
2 Afghanistan 2019                      Wine           0
3 Afghanistan 2019 Other alcoholic beverages           0
4     Algeria 2019 Other alcoholic beverages           0
5     Andorra 2019 Other alcoholic beverages           0
6     Austria 2019 Other alcoholic beverages           0
```

I would like to make it to wide format having a different column for each beverage for each country and year. For example

```
      Country Year  All types   Beer   Wine  Spirits   Other alcoholic beverages
1 Afghanistan 2019   0.01        0      0       0,1            0
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: `pivot_wider(df, c(Country, Year), names_from = Beverage, values_from = consumption)`

Comment: @Onyambu I am getting a warning and the returned tibble has lists insted of values in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# set dataframe as data.table
setDT(df)

# long to wide
dcast(df
      , country + year ~ beverage
      , value.var = 'consumption'
      )
```

Comment: I tried this but getting a warning, Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do. As we haven't provided the `fun` argument, `dcast` defaults to `fun=length`.
If you would like to count rows then the default (as what it is doing now) does the job.
However, if you are looking to sum then use `fun=sum`